# Using Googlemaps in Yii2?

Tags: google-maps, yii2, yii-extensions

How do I use Googlemaps in Yii2 ?

I am not able to follow the `Usage` placed in http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/yii2-google-maps-library

Installation has been done, but I am getting error

```
Class 'dosamigos\google\maps\LatLng' not found
```

Could anyone provide a tutorial/examples where Yii uses Google Maps ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally the use directive for third party extensione start with vendor 
could be you must add the vendor to the use  where you use these class.

try using

```
use vendor\dosamigos\google\maps\LatLng;
use vendor\dosamigos\google\maps\services\DirectionsWayPoint;
use vendor\dosamigos\google\maps\services\TravelMode;
use vendor\dosamigos\google\maps\overlays\PolylineOptions;
use vendor\dosamigos\google\maps\services\DirectionsRenderer;
use vendor\dosamigos\google\maps\services\DirectionsService;
use vendor\dosamigos\google\maps\overlays\InfoWindow;
use vendor\dosamigos\google\maps\overlays\Marker;
use vendor\dosamigos\google\maps\Map;
use vendor\dosamigos\google\maps\services\DirectionsRequest;
use vendor\dosamigos\google\maps\overlays\Polygon;
use vendor\dosamigos\google\maps\layers\BicyclingLayer;
```